# Reading submehes of a 3D object in Android ARCore

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, arcore, sceneform

I am looking for a way in Android native to be able to read the sub meshes of a 3D object (OBJ, gLTF, FBX) dynamically. I am currently using Android arcore-sceneform SDK and couldn't find any class that does it.

The reason why I want to do that is because I want to detect user's tap on a particular sub-mesh and trigger an action (show/hide a label) accordingly. For example, if there's a hand object, I want to trigger separate actions when user taps on individual fingers of the hand, where hand is one object.

Has anyone done it before or know how to do it?

Comment: You might want to explain why you are trying to pull out a sub mesh, given that its just a bunch a triangle vertices. Looking for [Sceneform Collisions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50572532/295004) perhaps?

Comment: I have responded to your query by clarifying my question a little bit. Hope that helps.

Comment: In my mind, I would make up the hand & fingers as individual objects (for highlighting) rather than one mesh object. Related: [how to check ray intersection with object in ARCore](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46017301/295004) and note the number of objects in this sample: https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/sceneform/animation/animation-quickstart

Comment: @PHP Developer Were you able to achieve this? I want to apply different texture on sub meshes and this where I am stuck.

Comment: @GunjanDave In my case, the model I was using didn't have any submeshes. It was just one big blob. If you have an object with multiple submeshes you can simply loop through them such as `GameObject.FindObbjectOfType<>.gameObject.transform.GetChild(i)` Hope this helps

Comment: @PHPDeveloper How this can be done with SceneForms. I know this can be achieved with Unity 3d, but not sure how can be achieved with SCENEFORMS.